# Adding a new field to existing Crystal report from a new table not already in the report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a existing crystal report with a query and a few tables already selected and some fields from those tables on the report.

Now I want to add a new field `(p.price)` on  the same report, from a new table `(item_price)` that is not already in the report and that has some query logic behind it like:

```
select  i.rrp_price, p.price from ITEM i
inner join ITEM_PRICE p on i.item_code = p.item_code 
 and  price_type = 'P1' and break_count = 0
```

I am using VS 2010 and the Crystal Reports functionality of it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just edit the original underlying query to include the extra fields that you require...

Comment: I have updated the query. But I dont know how to add new field to report design.

Comment: you should be able to open the report file in visual studio and in the field explorer, right click on database fields and choose verify database. that should push the updated db/query info into the crystal report.